# sorting strings using bucket sort

Tags: c, sorting, c-strings, bucket-sort

I want to sort set of strings accordingly their length using bucket sort in C.
I know another way to do such thing, like this one:

```
void sort(char* s[], int n, int m) {
    char *helper[n];
    int lengths[n], curr=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    helper[i]=s[i];
    lengths[i]=strlen(s[i]);
    }

    for(int k=0; k<=m; ++k)//for each length
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) //copy strings of length k to s
    {
        if(lengths[i]==k)
        s[curr++]=helper[i];
    }
    }
```

but I would like to do it using bucket sort.
Someone has any idea how to do it?

Comment: Put into buckets... Sort items in buckets... Take from buckets... Done!

Comment: I can't take from buckets items like strings.
From example ,I have 4 strings in length 5. and 3 strings in length 4.
How I can sort them using bucket sort

Comment: @SaniHuttunen It's even simpler: Put into buckets... Take from buckets... Done!  Victor: Each bucket needs to be able to store a number of strings. You can provide storage using for example a linked list for each bucket.

Comment: I think, if you want to have faster way, you can store length and indexes. Then sort the matrix, based on length, through quicksort and use the sorted martix to return the strings sorted.

Comment: @Victor Are you familiar with most-significant-digit radix sort? If not, have you heard of the trie data structure?

Comment: Could someone write  a specific code for such sort in C?

Comment: Do you want the bucket sort function to be passed the string length limit, as is the case with your sort function? Do you want to specify the number of buckets?